# How to programmatically change highlighted item in the spark combobox

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I want to change the highlighted item in the spark combobox programmatically. 
When the combobox popup is opened with selected item it shows as highlighted color in the popup.With the popup opened now i changed the selected item programatically by setting selectedIndex and selectedItem properties.The text input got changed with the given selected item but the highlighted color is still showing the previous value. How to change that highlighted item to the selected item.
Can any one please provide solution to this one.

```
public class AutoSortComboBox extends ComboBox{



    public function AutoSortComboBox ():void    {   
                super();   
    }
    protected function sortDataProvider(descending:Boolean):void{

                var arrColl:ArrayCollection = this.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
                var selectedItem:Object = this.selectedItem as Object;
                this.selectedIndex = -1;
                var dataSortField:SortField = new SortField();
                dataSortField.name = "label";
                dataSortField.numeric = false;
                dataSortField.descending = descending;
                /* Create the Sort object and add the SortField object created earlier to the array of fields to sort on. */
                var numericDataSort:Sort = new Sort();
                numericDataSort.fields = [dataSortField];
                arrColl.sort = numericDataSort;
                arrColl.refresh();
                if(selectedItem != null)
                {
                    for(var i:int=0;i<arrColl.length;i++)
                    {
                        if(selectedItem.label == arrColl[i].label)
                            this.selectedIndex = i;
                    }
                    this.selectedItem = selectedItem;
                }
     }
  }
```

Comment: I'm unclear if you're asking about how to style the highlighted item in a Spark ComboBox; or if you're asking about how to change which item is highlighted.

Comment: Sorry for not clear i am asking how to change which item is highlighted

Comment: There is a method in combobox changeHighlightedSelection which is internal i want to call that changeHighlightedSelection method programatically. How to call that method to change highlighted selection item

Answer (score 0):

one of these two should work:

```
FocusManager.SetFocus(DisplayObject)
```

or

```
 Combobox.selectedItem = ItemFromCombobox
```

Comment: Try with this callLater(function():void{Combobox.selectedItem = ItemFromCombobox});

Comment: Hey Raja Jaganathan thanks for your solution. I tried with callLater which you have given.Its working but the problem is i got two highlighted items now one is previous selected item and the other is newly selected item. How to remove previous highlighted item.

Comment: I am unable to post the screenshot here other wise it will be more clear to you

Comment: May be you need to revisit your for loop statement for selecting item with out BREAK statement or your arraycollection label values may duplicated.